# While using a socket to send and receive passwords, does it encrypt the data?

Tags: node.js, sockets, security, encryption, passwords

I'm trying to make a login and sign-up system (I am hashing and salting the password). When I send the password to the server I'm using `socket.emit()` to send and receive data. Does socket automatically encrypt and decrypt the data or should I make my own custom encryption and decryption algorithm using [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem))?

Comment: Are you initiating the socket.io connection over https?  If so, it will run within that TLS encrypted channel and the target server will also have some protection against endpoint hijaacking or spoofing.  socket.io runs on the webSocket protocol which also has it's own encryption, but you really should be using an https server for the connection to get all the benefits it provides.

Comment: Good question. Feel free to play with wireshark and inspect your own traffic to see whether it is encrypted or not.